# How should weights be optimized with gradient descent algorithm in order to work?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have a neural network in visual studio. for the loss function I am using a basic cost function (pred-target)**2 and after I finish an epoch I optimize the parameter functions afterwards, but the algorithm doesn't work.

No matter what is my network configuration, the predictions are not write (it is the same output for all the inputs) and the loss function is not optimized. It stays the same through all the epochs.

```
void calc_lyr(int x, int y, int idx, float target) // thus function calculates the neuron value based on the previous layer
{
    if (x == -1 || y == 0) // if its the first layer, get the data from input nodes
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < neurons[y]; i++)
        {
            float sum = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < inputTypes.Count; j++)
            {
                sum += weights[x+1][j][i] * training_test[idx][j];
            }
            sum = relu(sum);
            vals[y+1][i] = sum;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < neurons[y]; i++)
        {
            float sum = 0;

            for(int j = 0; j < neurons[x]; j++)
            {
                sum += weights[x+1][j][i] * vals[x+1][j] + biases[y][i];
            }
            sum = relu(sum);
            vals[y+1][i] = sum;
        }
    }
}

void train()
{
    log("Proces de antrenare inceput ----------------- " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

    vals = new List<List<float>>();
    weights = new List<List<List<float>>>();
    biases = new List<List<float>>();

    Random randB = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    Random randW = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

    for (int i = 0; i <= nrLayers; i++)
    {
        progressEpochs.Value =(int)(((float)i * (float)nrLayers) / 100.0f);

        vals.Add(new List<float>());

        weights.Add(new List<List<float>>());
        if (i == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputTypes.Count; j++)
            {
                vals[i].Add(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            biases.Add(new List<float>());

            for (int j = 0; j < neurons[i-1]; j++)
            {
                vals[i].Add(0);

                float valB = (float)randB.NextDouble();
                biases[i-1].Add(valB - ((int)valB));
            }
        }
    }

    float valLB = (float)randB.NextDouble();

    biases.Add(new List<float>());
    biases[nrLayers].Add(valLB - ((int)valLB));


    for (int i = 0; i <= nrLayers; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputTypes.Count; j++)
            {
                weights[i].Add(new List<float>());

                for (int x = 0; x < neurons[i]; x++)
                {
                    float valW = (float)randW.NextDouble();
                    weights[i][j].Add(valW);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (i == nrLayers)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < neurons[i-1]; j++) {
                weights[i].Add(new List<float>());
                weights[i][j].Add(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < neurons[i - 1]; j++)
            {
                weights[i].Add(new List<float>());

                for (int x = 0; x < neurons[i]; x++)
                {
                    float valW = (float)randW.NextDouble();
                    weights[i][j].Add(valW);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    log("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < epochs; i++)
    {
        log("Epoch " + (i + 1).ToString() + " inceput ---> " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        int idx = rand.Next() % training_test.Count;

        float target = outputsPossible.IndexOf(training_labels[idx]);

        for (int j = 0; j < nrLayers; j++)
        {
            calc_lyr(j - 1, j, idx, target);
        }

        float total_val = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < neurons[nrLayers - 1]; x++)
        {
            float val = relu(weights[nrLayers][x][0] * vals[nrLayers][x] + biases[nrLayers][0]);
            total_val += val;
        }

        total_val = sigmoid(total_val);

        float cost_res = cost(total_val, target);

        log("Epoch " + (i+1).ToString() + " terminat ----- " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n");
        log("Eroare epoch ---> " + (cost_res<1?"0":"") + cost_res.ToString("##.##") + "\n\n\n");

        float cost_der = cost_d(total_val, target);

        for (int a = 0; a < weights.Count; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < weights[a].Count; b++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < weights[a][b].Count; c++)
                {
                    weights[a][b][c]-=cost_der*learning_rate * sigmoid_d(weights[a][b][c]);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int a = 0; a < nrLayers; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < neurons[a]; b++)
            {
                biases[a][b] -= cost_der * learning_rate;
            }
        }

    }
    hasTrained = true;
    testBut.Enabled = hasTrained;
    MessageBox.Show("Antrenament complet!");

    SavePrompt sp = new SavePrompt();
    sp.Show();
}
```

How can it be changed to optimize the weights, biases and loss function? For now, when I try to debug, the weights are changing, but it is the same value for the loss function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using AForge.NET: [link](http://www.aforgenet.com)